# Validation error when saving a record to database nest.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, nestjs

I'm following along with this tutorial:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/build-web-apis-with-nestjs-beginners-guide/

I'm trying to save a user record to the PostGres DB and I'm getting the following error

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "Users" ("id","name","email","password","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5) RETURNING "id","name","email","password","createdAt","updatedAt";
[Nest] 17906  - 10/04/2023, 2:37:20 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Validation error
Error: 
    at Query.run (/Users/grahammorby/Documents/GitHub/dcuk-api/node_modules/sequelize/src/dialects/postgres/query.js:76:25)
    at /Users/grahammorby/Documents/GitHub/dcuk-api/node_modules/sequelize/src/sequelize.js:650:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at PostgresQueryInterface.insert (/Users/grahammorby/Documents/GitHub/dcuk-api/node_modules/sequelize/src/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js:795:21)
    at User.save (/Users/grahammorby/Documents/GitHub/dcuk-api/node_modules/sequelize/src/model.js:4153:35)
    at Function.create (/Users/grahammorby/Documents/GitHub/dcuk-api/node_modules/sequelize/src/model.js:2305:12)
    at UsersService.create (/Users/grahammorby/Documents/GitHub/dcuk-api/src/core/modules/users/users.service.ts:12:16)
    at AuthService.create (/Users/grahammorby/Documents/GitHub/dcuk-api/src/core/modules/auth/auth.service.ts:41:25)
    at AuthController.signUp (/Users/grahammorby/Documents/GitHub/dcuk-api/src/core/modules/auth/auth.controller.ts:18:16)
    at /Users/grahammorby/Documents/GitHub/dcuk-api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:46:28
```

Here is my Service:

```js
public async create(user) {
   // hash the password
    const pass = await this.hashPassword(user.password);

    // create the user
    const newUser = await this.userService.create({ ...user, password: pass });

    // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
    const { password, ...result } = newUser['dataValues'];

    // generate token
    const token = await this.generateToken(result);

    // return the user and the token
    return { user: result, token };
}

private async generateToken(user) {
    const token = await this.jwtService.signAsync(user);
    return token;
}

private async hashPassword(password) {
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    return hash;
}
```

My DTO:

```js
import { IsNotEmpty, MinLength, IsEmail } from "class-validator";

export class UserDto {
    @IsNotEmpty()
    readonly name: string;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsEmail()
    readonly email: string;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @MinLength(6)
    readonly password: string;
}
```

User Service:

```js
async create(user: UserDto): Promise<User> {
    return await this.userRepository.create<User>(user);
}
```

Comment: Any stack trace, extra information, other error info you can add? There's not much here

Comment: Added the full error